# Real time application on Microsoft Windows 7 Pro

Tags: c++, windows, multithreading, visual-studio-2010, real-time

I have opened this new thread after having tried lots of thing. 
My application (C++ on VS2010) has to grab an image, elaborate the image, send through UDP the result. The problem is the frequency: 200 times/second. So I have a camera that records image in a double buffer at 200Hz, and I have to elaborate the image in less than 5 milliseconds. The application works at 99,999 % of the time but I think that Win7 Pro take out my realtime priority and so in 1 of 100000 cases something goes wrong.
Reading msdn forum and so on, I can only use:

1. SetPriorityClass(GetCurrentProcess(), REALTIME_PRIORITY_CLASS); To get a realtime priority of the process when it have been launched with administrator's priviledges
2. SetThreadPriority(HANDLE, THREAD_PRIORITY_ABOVE_NORMAL); or THREAD_PRIORITY_HIGHEST or THREAD_PRIORITY_TIME_CRITICAL.

Now, I have 5 threads started by me (_beginthreadex) and several thread started inside a compiled DLL of the camera. I think that if I set Time Critical priority to all my 5 thread, none of them has higher priority than others.

So I have two questions:

- could I work at 200 Hz without Windows's lags?
- have you any suggestions for my threads' settings?

Thanks!!
Bye bye
Paolo

Comment: What does 'something goes wrong' means?

Comment: Well.. image period 5ms, disk latency 10ms = misery.  Any swaps and you're stuffed, (on a spinner, anyway).  Still, I would expect that you could get close-ish to 5ms overall, with care, extra buffering and accepting a little latency.

Comment: @Martin James: I'm using a SSD in order to avoid that disk latency.

Comment: @Daniel Mosmondor: "something goes wrong" means that the camera overwrites the buffer while I'm elaborating it.. For example: if the camera swaps buffer every 5 millisecs, and my elaboration lasts 6 milliseconds then the camera overwrites a little of my buffer. I could use more than 2 buffers, but I must send a result every 5 milliseconds, so it doen't change the situation..

Comment: What is maximum delay between image and its 'summary' that you send through the UDP?  I am asking that because you say that you have to send datagrams every 5ms, but you don't say what is their timing in respect to the incoming picture...

Comment: @DanielMošmondor: the timing is 5 milliseconds (200 Hz). There is a new image every 5 milliseconds and I have to elaborate the "previous" image in less than 5 milliseconds. So new images @ 200 Hz, new results @ 200 Hz. Can I answer better? ;)

Comment: So you are saying that you have to send out picture summary BEFORE next picture is captured, right?

Comment: when the event of "picutre ready" raises up, I send the result of latest elaboration (previous picture)

Answer (score 0):

Oh I would use more than two buffers for this.  A pool of 200 image objects seems like a better bet.

How much latency can you afford, overall?  It's always the same story with video streaming - you can have consistent, pause-free operation, or low latency, but not both.

How big is the video image buffer queue on the client side?

Edit:

'I must ever send a UDP datagram every 5 millisec' :((

OK, so you have an image output queue with a UDP send thread on a 5ms loop, yes? The queue must never empty.  Sounds indeed like the elaborations are the bottleneck.

Do you have a [number of cores+] pool of threads doing the elaborations?

Comment: I used a double buffer because I must ever send a UDP datagram every 5 millisec. So, I could use a 200-image buffer, but I have to break the elaboration if I'm overlapping the 5-ms period..